# NocloassDefFound Error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, noclassdeffounderror

I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` when trying to build a maven project in eclipse. Where as it builds successfully on command line

I get the above mentioned class through the following dependency defined in the pom

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

--I tried, deleting the local repo and running the build with -U option but doesnt seem to fix the problem.

--When I look at the java build path in eclipse, it shows certain libraries missing. I  found newer versions of these jars in the local repo and added them in the eclipse java build path. But the build still fails for the same error

Note: I have one multimodule project in my eclipse workspace.

--I tried updating the project and verified if eclipse was using teh same settings.xml and local repo that the command line is.
--I am running a clean install

--Cleaning project also doesnt fix it

--I looked at the referrenced libraries and there is a class org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager present. Dont know why it doesnt find it

Comment: try closing all projects to isolate issue to single project. also there should be no need to modify build path manually, it probably adds to your issues

Comment: I just have dependent modules in teh workspace which I need open for it to compile

Comment: if you close dependent modules then eclipse should pickup jars from your local maven repo

Comment: I ams orry, so this module is a dependency for the module in question.

Answer (score 0):

If project builds on command line it should build in Eclipse as well. Reasons why it may not be the case include:

1. settings.xml used by Eclipse is different, so Maven does not have access to same repos. This can be changed in preferences.
2. Workspace resolution is picking code in dependent projects that have local changes and thus build fails
3. Eclipse maven configuration is not up-to-date that can be fixed by using Maven->Update project .. option

Try that if it fails please clarify if you have one project in Eclipse or multiple and what errors exactly do you see.

Also note that sometimes maven build from command line will delete target folder and will cause Eclipse to run build in parallel re-using same target folder and resulting in inconsistent state.

Comment: Hi, I just edited the questions based on the answer, doesn't seem to still fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding dependency for HttpCore library, the class exists there too

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
<artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
<version>4.4.3</version>
```

Comment: It does get this dependency from a dependent module. Even after eplicitly adding this dependency in its own pom, doesnt fix it

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that I had two versions of http-client library. I excluded one of them from the pom